# How to display a text popup on single click and download on double click?

Tags: android

I am busy editing the aptoide code from github into something that will be used for users to suggest apps and be able to browse and download suggested apps.

The only problem is that aptoide does not display any explaination of what the app is.

So I would like to know firstly, is it possible to code a if single-click event and a double-click event?

And secondly, how would I go about coding this? I would like the single-click to show the info about the app and the double click to download the app. So you'd click the suggested app, it'll show the info and then you click again to download.

I am using Eclipse with the ADT plugin.

I have tried to be as thorough as possible.

I am not very good with eclipse and android just yet, so you might have to spoon feed me here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Long press is the standard action people expect not double tap, 
Check out the [`AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) docs

Maybe I'm not understanding correctly what you're trying to do
Do you mean you want to change the OnClickListener once the first one has been run.

Comment: That would work. And would be better than double click. I didn't even think of the long click adapter. Thanks so much, going to go through the docs now, will be back if I need help

Comment: no worries, a quick search on here/google will probably give you plenty examples of implementation. It's very similar to the `OnItemClickListener`